# How to optimize evaluation of hessian in sympy?

Tags: sympy, statsmodels, numexpr

I'm using `statsmodels` library for generic likelihood models. As I have a quite complicated likelihood function, I used `sympy` to calculate gradient and hessian for me. This works fine, but it is too slow for my needs, because likelihood function contains term `b0*x0 + b1*x1 + ... + bn*xn`. That way hessian size increases by `N^2` and so does the complexity.

Elements of the hessian are often pretty similar like `expensive_operation * x0` and `expensive_operation * x1`, etc. It means that if I could pre-calculate `expensive_operation` and use it in functions in hessian, I would drastically increase performance.

So the question is - is there a tool which would take list of functions, optimize them and then evaluate them effectively? Something like `numexpr` which would take list of functions?

Comment: SymPy has `cse`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. If you write it as regular post, I will accept it.

Comment: You should also look at Theano, and the Theano/SymPy integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy has `cse`, which stands for common subexpression elimination. See [the docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#cse).

A simple example:

```
>>> print(cse(sin(x**2)*cos(x**2) + 2*sin(x**2) - cos(x**2)))
([(x0, x**2), (x1, sin(x0)), (x2, cos(x0))], [x1*x2 + 2*x1 - x2])
```